# how to make checkboxes work in accordance with labels c#(yahtzee)

Tags: c#

[image]
This is my form running, i want to code the checkboxes so that they can hold the picture of their specific dice

```
Image[] diceImages;
int[] dice;
Random rand;

#endregion

#region Initialization

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    diceImages=new Image[7];
    diceImages[0] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_0;
    diceImages[1] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_1;
    diceImages[2] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_2;
    diceImages[3] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_3;
    diceImages[4] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_4;
    diceImages[5] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_5;
    diceImages[6] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_6;

    dice = new int[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    rand = new Random();
}

#endregion

private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)
        dice[i] = rand.Next(1, 7);

    Array.Sort(dice);

    lblDie1.Image = diceImages[dice[0]];
    lblDie2.Image = diceImages[dice[1]];
    lblDie3.Image = diceImages[dice[2]];
    lblDie4.Image = diceImages[dice[3]];
    lblDie5.Image = diceImages[dice[4]];
}

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void chk4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

i have created 5 checkboxes with names chk1-5, i have tried fitting the code in but it doesn't work, could someone help me make this code work.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: i need to fit checkboxes in their for each of the labels, so that it can frfeeze the label when ticked

Comment: It would help immensely if you posted a screenshot of what you want the UI to look like...

Comment: @Ghost: Please edit your question, make clear what EXACTLY you want and try to write in correct sentences.

Comment: You need to read [ask].

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar could you take a look now

Comment: @Ghost Did you read my answer about using a `UserControl`? Also, your UI is not dynamic. Why not select both a dice and its check box and use the Visual Studio alignment tools to center them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your question is pretty unclear as to how you actually want your UI to look like, what might help is the use of `UserControl`s:

You could make a new `UserControl` named `DiceControl` that combines **one** dice image and its corresponding `CheckBox`. You can then put multiple instances of that control on your form in the designer as if it were just one control. That might help you align stuff the way you want.

All you need to do is create methods/properties on the `DiceControl` that allow you to get/set the current image and the current hold status.